# How to create a subclass in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, subclassing

How do I create a subclass in C# for ASP.NET using Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
public class Foo
{}

public class Bar : Foo
{}
```

In this case, Bar is the sub class.

Answer (score 31):

Here is an example of writing a ParentClass and then creating a ChildClass as a sub class.

```
using System;

public class ParentClass
{
    public ParentClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent Constructor.");
    }

    public void print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a Parent Class.");
    }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public ChildClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child Constructor.");
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ChildClass child = new ChildClass();

        child.print();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Parent Constructor.
Child Constructor.
I'm a Parent Class.
```

Rather than rewriting yet another example of .Net inheritance I have copied a decent example from the [C Sharp Station website](https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson08).

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean class inheritance?

```
public class SubClass: MasterClass
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/C_Sharp_Inheritance) explains it well:

```
public class SavingsAccount : BankAccount
{
    public double interestRate;

    public SavingsAccount(string name, int number, int balance, double rate) : base(name, number)
    {
        accountBalance = balance;
        interestRate = rate;
    }

    public double monthlyInterest()
    {
        return interestRate * accountBalance;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    SavingsAccount saveAccount = new SavingsAccount("Fred Wilson", 123456, 432, 0.02F);

    Console.WriteLine("Interest this Month = " + saveAccount.monthlyInterest());
}
```

If the `monthlyInterest` method already exists in the `BankAccount` class (and is declared `abstract`, `virtual`, or `override`) then the `SavingsAccount` method definition should include `override`, as explained [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Understanding_C_Sharp_Abstract_Classes). Not using `override` to redefine such class methods will result in a CS0108 compiler warning, which can be suppressed by using `new` as confusingly stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39.aspx).