# Show a control in designer when the Visiblity's Fallbackvalue is set to 'Hidden'

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017, designer

in several Views we have container components - for example `Grid` or `ScrollViewer`- that are bound to a property on their own ViewModel or ViewModelItem.

In some cases the View (parent) containing these components can be shown without the ViewModel/ViewModelItem of the components being initialized. To avoid showing a user empty datagrids we are using `FallBackValue=Hidden` to make sure the container is only shown when it's ViewModel/ViewModelItem is initialized/loaded.

A hypothetical example would be a `Window` containing a `DataGrid` and a more detailed view to the right. The detailed view would be its own `UserControl` with its own ViewModel and the `DataGrid` would have its own `ViewModel` as well. When opening said `Window` the ViewModel of the `DataGrid` would be loaded immediately - but since no row has been selected the ViewModel that belongs to the detailed View would not be intialized, which means that the `Visibility` Binding of the detail View would fail and the binding's `FallbackValue` would be used to hide the detail View.
The issue with this approach is that the Visual Studio WPF/XAML designer will not show the content of the affected containers since they are hidden due to their FallbackValue.

Question: Is there a way to get the designer to show specific controls/components that have the `FallBackValue` of a `Visibility` binding set to `Hidden`? Clicking into the XAML code that is inside these hidden containers does *not* show them.

---

#### Edit 1

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278611/937093) answer. Setting `d:IsHidden="false"` does not help. Regardless of if it's set before or after the `Visibility` property.

Comment: Have you set the Design Data Context? We could do with some code examples. `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VM.ViewModel"`And then `d:DataContext ="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm:YourViewModelNameHere}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"`

Comment: @XAMlMAX wow that's a nice snippet and it works for a few cases! The only issue I have is that in most cases the constructor of the ViewModel would call methods of other classes that - due to MEF - are unknown to the designer.

Comment: I think Blend gives you more flexibility for creating Design Time instance have a look at [this MSDN post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn169081.aspx).

Comment: @XAMlMAX yeah stumbled over this ~30 minutes ago ;). Seems a bit overwhelming at the moment. My current idea is to create a subclass of the specific types and use the default constructor of the subtype. Oh also could you re-phrase your comments into an answer? Because that essentially solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to the designer you would have to set the Design Data Context.
To do that you would typically do the following in your xaml file:

```
<Control, Page or Window
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VM.ViewModel"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm:YourViewModelNameHere}, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" 
    .../>
```

However, sometimes like in your case, more flexibility is needed for the complex ViewModel. For this I would use `Blend` and it's functionality, what that is it will generate dummy data for you and set the data context of the Control for you.
For more information refer to this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn169081.aspx) article.

Comment: thank you! As for the cases where the default constructor of the ViewModel calls upon MEF or other methods that would throw exceptions I created a [subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4245831/937093), added a default constructor that sets the bound properties to appropiate values. I then added a new constructor to the ViewModel that has a dummy parameter - I created a `DummyDesigner` class just for that constructor - and used the `: base(new DummyDesigner())` syntax to make the subclass's default constructor call that new constructor on the ViewModel